# Geolocation API is not working on my mobile phone but on desktop does

Tags: javascript, android, api, geolocation, gps

I developed a map with OpenStreetMap that should locate my current position.
On desktop all working fine, but when I switch to mobile phone he doesn't ask for GPS permissions and it doesn't work.

After creating the map (on phone it displays error):

```
function init() {
    createMap('map');
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
}

function createMap(id) {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map(id);
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
}

function success(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log(latitude + ', ' + longitude);

    addMarker(latitude, longitude);
    setCenter(latitude, longitude);
}

function setCenter(latitude, longitude) {
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitude, latitude).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject())

        , 18
    );
}

function addMarker(latitude, longitude) {
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitude, latitude).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject())
    ));
}

function error() {
    alert(`ERROR(${error.code}): ${error.message}`);
}
```

Comment: which desktop, which mobile phone? what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, Geolocation only works on HTTPS and I was accessing the site from the phone as an HTTP site